# How to extract union prop from an array of objects?

Tags: typescript

I have array of objects

```
const data = [{ test: 'first'}, { test: 'second'} ]
```

How I can get union type that looks like:

```
const TestType = 'first' | 'second'
```

from this array?

Probably we can infer it somehow, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is actually a way to do this.
For it to work though you would need to include an `as const` assertion to the `data` array.

**Example:**

```
const data = [{ test: 'first'}, { test: 'second'} ] as const
const dataForType = [...data.map(d => d.test)]

type TestType = typeof dataForType[number];
```

So basically we create a new array, iterate over the original `data` array and return the values of all corresponding `test` keys.
Then we create a union type that is the culmination of all these values.

Perhaps there is a shorter way to write this, but this is the gist of it.

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=44&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3jKBTaALhgHIAzASwCdoSBfAGhh3yNIj1DDnpgF0YCCDC7QAUKNiJkAMRBUAKgE8ADnjSYAdNukJNAWwQqAFHDQA+eJtZQAlHzFioq9QoJRlajc7Ugy8JAQ5RRcMMABXfQAjPCo+AG4xGBggA)

Comment: But can we do it just with TS?

Comment: Based on the structure of `data`, I don't think so. If instead of an array of objects it would be an array of the string values, then yes. But the way it currently is, you would need to extract the relevant `test` values by iterating over the original array. I could be wrong though.

Comment: but what about infer?

Comment: This also infers the type. For example, if you were to add `{test: 'third'}` to the `data` array, then it would be part of the type as well. But ultimately we need a way to create an array of strings instead of an array of objects.